# Prestashop hook ModuleRoutes

Tags: prestashop, hook, prestashop-1.7

I have a problem with register hook and i cant find good documentation about moduleRoutes
my hook function :

```
public function hookModuleRoutes()
{
    return [
        'module-youtube_video-display' => [
            'controller' => 'display',
            'rule' => 'youtube_video',
            'params' => [
                'fc' => 'module',
                'module' => 'youtube_video'
                ]
        ]
    ];
}
```

> modules\youtube_video\vpages\controllers\front\display.php

```
class VpagesDisplayModuleFrontController extends ModuleFrontController {
public function init(){
    parent::init();
    $this->setTemplate('youtube_video.tpl');
}
```

}

> modules\youtube_video\views\templates\hook\youtube_video.tpl

```
<div id="custom-text">
<p>{$youtube_url}</p></div>
```

i try this with difrent tutorials and still get 404 when i try go to route

Answer (score 1):

You forgot a some features of Prestashop like 'link rewrite' and 'language'.
Try this:

```
public function hookModuleRoutes($params)
{
    $head = Configuration::get('your_config', $this->language->id);
    $my_youtube_video = array(
        'module-youtube_video-display' => array(
            'controller' => 'display',
            'rule' => $head . '/youtube_video/{link_rewrite}',
            'keywords' => array(
                'link_rewrite' =>   array('regexp' => '[_a-zA-Z0-9-\pL]*', 'param' => 'link_rewrite'),
            ),
            'params' => array(
                'fc' => 'module',
                'module' => 'youtube_video',
            ),
        )
    );

    return $my_youtube_video;
}
```

And why do you have the 'vpages' in here? Why not just modules\youtube_video\controllers\front\display.php

And don't forget upon module install:

```
$this->registerHook('moduleRoutes');
```